# How to INSERT INTO database with a limit of 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't think this is a simple *LIMIT* query.
I have **organisers** that have **categories**.
Each organiser can only have 3 categories.
My problem is that I have a page to edit their categories and if I use a regular INSERT, then it may exceed 3 categories.

1. Some organisers may have 2 categories, and then choose to update to have 3.
2. Some organisers can have 3 categories, and update to have 2.
3. An organiser must have at least 1 category (this is handled on the client side).

**EDIT:**
My <s>current solution</s> currently implemented solution is to delete all categories before inserting the modified ones, then using the client-side to restrict the limit to 3. I'm using **MySQL**. The database is normalised like so:

```
       organiser                                     organiser_categories
  +-------------------+                    +-------------------+--------------+
  |  organiser_email  |                    |  organiser_email  | category_id  |
  +-------------------+                    +-------------------+--------------+
  |  abc@gmail.com    |                    |   abc@gmail.com   |     1        |
  |  xyz@gmail.com    |                    |   abc@gmail.com   |     2        |
  +-------------------+                    +-------------------+--------------+


                             categories
                 +---------------+---------------+
                 |  category_id  | category_name |
                 +---------------+---------------+
                 |      1        |    Leisure    |
                 |      2        |    History    |
                 +---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you could do the checking (limit to 3 category) at the app site instead of at mysql. That is part of the verification of data.

When updating to database, i do agree with you to delete all categories and inserting the categories.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently, I am using Javascript to ensure that the client can't select more than 3 categories. Is it not redundant to delete all categories and insert the updates? I thought there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Delete and insert the updates would be faster than update in terms of speed especially comes to a large database.

Comment: That seems to make sense. I omitted it from the *organiser\category* table above, but there is an auto-increment ID field. I'm concerned about the field running above the memory limit. Would it be advisable to delete that ID field?

Comment: Regarding the memory limit of auto increment ID field, this is something that i never thought of. However, i don't see any need of auto increment ID in the `organiser\category table`.

Comment: I agree that there is most likely no need for the ID field. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1:

Enforce the limit through a trigger.

*Pros/cons: This keeps the data model general and you'll easily change the limit if necessary, but involves additional querying (i.e. counting of rows).*

#### Option 2:

Do the update through a stored procedure, and enforce the limit there.

*Pros/cons: Similar to above.*

#### Option 3:

Redesign your model: get rid of `organiser_categories` and add 3 NULL-able FK fields to `organiser` to store up to 3 categories.

*Pros/cons: This ensures the conformance to the limit without additional performance penalty, but requires a change in querying logic and would be relatively hard to evolve after the fact. Also, it contains more information than necessary: the "position" of the category (based on which of these 3 fields represents it).*

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort with your answer. I have never used triggers, so I'm wondering, will your solutions meet the numbered criteria in my original post? (I edited it a few minutes ago).

Comment: @user1037894 Well, a trigger (**option 1**) will have trouble enforcing the minimum - it is run only in response to actual DML operations and it won't even run if you don't touch `organiser_categories`. Stored procedures (**option 2**) might be more suitable for that: you'll have one more stored procedure for inserting a new organizer, that also accepts the one required category and then performs the insert both in `organiser` and `organiser_categories`. As for the **option 3**, just make one of the fields NOT NULL to ensure there is at least one category.

Comment: I think I'll rule out **option 1** (as you said it will have trouble with the minimum) and **option 3** (as it's not scalable). I'll have a look into **option 2**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to restrict the user with selection limit 3 at client side. And this is better approach to delete respective data for an organizer and reinsert them.

```
delete from organiser_categories where organizer_email='abc@xyz.com';
insert into organiser_categories (organiser,category) 
values ('abc@xyz.com',1), ('abc@xyz.com',3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and code example. Like I mentioned to @sel, is it not redundant to delete it all and insert again?

Comment: This is best approach acc to me and better then you find out the current exist records by hitting a select query and later then updating the existing rows and when organiser do select 3 categories from past 1, now you will fire a select, one update and one insert query. And thats really not good !!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* define a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `organiser_categories` that rejects new records if they would take the total number of categories for that organiser to more than three:

```
CREATE TRIGGER limit_organiser_categories BEFORE INSERT ON organiser_categories
FOR EACH ROW
  IF (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT category_id)  -- prefer COUNT(*) if appropriate
    FROM   organiser_categories
    WHERE  organiser_email = NEW.organiser_email
  ) = 3 THEN
    CALL too_many_categories;           -- call a non-existant procedure
  END IF;
```

Whilst this enforces your restriction at the database, I would still advise performing similar checks at the client end in order to provide meaningful feedback to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the SQL. That trigger seems to be quite a hit to performance and I don't think it handles the issue with updates -- if an organiser has 3 existing categories and wishes to update to having 2, of a different type. I could be wrong because I'm not too familiar with triggers.

Comment: @user1037894 Yes, you'd need another (UPDATE) trigger for that. As for performance, please benchmark - this `SELECT COUNT ...` may or may not be an actual performance problem and you can't know until you measure on realistic amounts of data. BTW, the above should be `> 3`, not `= 3`.

Comment: @user1037894: For an organiser to "update" from 3 categories to 2, a record would presumably be deleted from `organiser_categories`?  I don't see how that would be a problem here (an `UPDATE` trigger, as Branko suggests, would have no bearing).  I agree that benchmarking is the best way to see if the performance hit here is too severe, although even if it is you might be able to make significant improvements with better indexing.  Re the `WHERE` criterion above, `= 3` is indeed correct (`> 3` would only fail when there are already 4 or more records).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My aim is to make my project as scalable as possible because I'm not sure how many people will actually be using it in the future.

Comment: @eggyal My understanding was that `category_id` would be UPDATEd. If this is implemented as a DELETE/INSERT instead, then yes, an UPDATE trigger is not necessary.

Comment: @eggyal Ahh... this is **BEFORE** INSERT. Yes, the `=3` should be correct then. BTW, is there any utility in using `>= 3` instead? Are there any concurrent scenarios where that might make sense?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: How could updating `category_id` change the number of categories for an organiser from 3 to 2? :S  (That said, if it's possible that a category gets reassigned to a different organiser via an `UPDATE` then such a trigger would indeed be necessary).  Also, an `AFTER INSERT` trigger would not be able to reject the insert, so could not work for this purpose in any event.  The only benefit I can see to `>= 3` is where an insert that bypassed the trigger (e.g. from before its creation) resulted in > 3 in the table and one wishes to prevent further additions.

Comment: @eggyal My brain isn't working correctly today ;) Yes you are correct, updating the `category_id` alone wouldn't change the number of categories per organiser. As for `AFTER INSERT`, wouldn't it [rollback the transaction on exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6634245/533120)? And as for `>=3`, would it be theoretically possible for one insert to start the trigger, then another insert start and finish, before first insert's trigger's SELECT has even started executing? Such situation shouldn't be impossible as an artifact of threading.

Comment: @eggyal In fact, the more I think about it the more it looks like some form of locking is necessary. Two transactions might insert concurrently, yet not see each other until COMMIT, so even `>=3` is probably not enough.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Good point.  The `SELECT` in the trigger ought to be [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html): that should resolve your concurrency concerns?

Comment: @eggyal Unfortunately I don't think this will protect us in case given organiser is not yet associated to any categories. To my knowledge, `FOR UPDATE` locks only the selected rows and doesn't place a "range lock". Since we are not selecting any rows in this case, there is nothing to lock, and we can still have the anomaly. I think only a table-level lock would be able to resolve this, but obviously this is not terribly good for scalability.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: I believe that `FOR UPDATE` performs gap locking.

Comment: @eggyal Hmm... yes if it locks an "empty" gap it would prevent the anomaly. The only thing left to resolve are deadlocks, which could theoretically occur if concurrent transactions lock rows in different order. While MySQL will almost certainly always execute this `SELECT` in the same order, perhaps you should add `ORDER BY`, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: A deadlock wouldn't break the concurrency safety of the above approach, although it would incur a performance penalty.  I think we're probably moving beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Based on the issues with concurrency that you are discussing, I think the safest way to implement this is by deleting the categories associated with the organiser and re-inserting them.